# Why content coming from single?

Tags: custom-post-types

Below is my **single.php** page's code:

```
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <h3>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </h3>
  <?php
    if ( in_category( 'salon' ) ) {
         get_template_part( 'content', 'salon' );
    } 
     if ( in_category( 'staff' ) ) {
         get_template_part( 'content', 'staff' );
    } 
    else {
        get_template_part( 'content', 'common' );
    }
 ?>
  <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Normally when I open any post it's fine, but when I open a salon page (**content-salon.php**) then the content comes out double because the common page (**content-common.php**) is loaded as well.

**Common page code**:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

**Salon page code**:

```
 <ul class="st_tabs">
      <?php
      // The Query
      query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'salon' ) );

      // The Loop
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <li><a href="#st_content_<?php echo the_slug(); ?>" rel="tab_<?php echo the_slug(); ?>" class="st_tab">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a></li>
      <?php endwhile;

      // Reset Query
      wp_reset_query();

      ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="#next" class="st_next"></a> </div>

  <div class="st_view_container">
          <div class="st_view">
           <?php
      // The Query
      query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'salon' ) );

      // The Loop
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div id="st_content_<?php echo the_slug(); ?>" class="st_tab_view">
             <?php the_content(); ?>

            </div>
            <?php endwhile;

      // Reset Query
      wp_reset_query();

      ?>
          </div>
```

Normal logic is when a salon category post is opened it will load the **content-salon.php** page and it's loading without any problem but it also loads the common page too... I have no idea why it's loading **content-common.php** as well.

Can you guys tell me where I am making a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution...please try this stuff......

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>   

<?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
if ( in_category('11') ) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single_our_services.php');
}    
elseif ( in_category('44') ) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single_rugged_product.php');
}             
elseif ( in_category('50') ) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/team_leader.php');
}
elseif ( in_category('50') ) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/saas_maker.php');
}
?>
<?php //get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: thanks @alex.. bellow one worked just now.. same like your almost... .can see my salon page.. have you better idea for that page

`<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div class="contentarea cf">
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <h3> <?php the_title(); ?></h3>
 
 <?php
  if ( in_category( 'salon' ) ) {
         get_template_part( 'content', 'salon' );
    } 
 
 elseif ( in_category( 'staff' ) ) {
         get_template_part( 'content', 'staff' );
    } else{
get_template_part( 'content', 'test' );
 }
?>

 
  <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
`

Comment: Note: `TEMPLATEPATH` is slated for deprecation. Please use `get_template_part()` in this context instead.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please don't use query posts, you're storing up a whole world of pain: [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/50762#50762)

As for the bug you're experiencing, taking a look at the logic:

```
 if ( in_category( 'salon' ) ) {
    //Include a particular template if I'm in category salon
 } 

 if ( in_category( 'staff' ) ) {
    //Include a particular template if I'm in category staff
 } else {
    //Include a particular template if I'm not in category staff
 }
```

Note that the `else` is only referring to the `is_category('staff')` conditional. And so if `is_category('salon')` is true, then the else is statement shall also be true (because `in_category( 'staff' )` would evaluate to false -unless its in both categories).

You want the structure:

```
 if( ... ){

 }elseif( ... ){

 }else{

 }
```

Comment: thanks i tired and it work.. thanks a ton.... but if i don't use query_posts then how could mate that page. i wanted show that page all post. see my salon page will show all post. i am not so expart on wordpress and php. if you have better idea. then please share with me

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding alternatives to query_posts() see the question I linked to. Otherwise, see: http://developer.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/querying-posts-without-query_posts/, http://digwp.com/2011/05/loops/ or my own article: http://stephenharris.info/die-query_posts-die/ )

Comment: thanks @Stephen... ok now see.. my full code.. it's working but technically is this ok ?